# Add more flags to Mail OSX client

Tags: macos, mail.app

Is there any way to add more flags to Mail.app (Mountain Lion 10.8.4)? I have a lot of subprojects, and need more flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MailTags from http://www.indev.ca can provide you with a number of ways to tag messages in Mail.

You are not going to get a lot of love out of Apple's mail.app otherwise.